# Rails find_by - Association comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I've got three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :surveys
end
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :survey_sessions
end
class SurveySession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

My question:

If this is possible:

```
Survey.find_by!(id: params[:id], user: current_user)
```

Why does this throw a SQLException at me?

```
SurveySession.joins(:survey)
    .find_by!(id: params[:id], surveys: {user: current_user})


SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: surveys.user: 
SELECT "survey_sessions".* FROM "survey_sessions" INNER JOIN "surveys" ON "surveys"."id" = "survey_sessions"."survey_id" WHERE "survey_sessions"."id" = 3 AND "surveys"."user" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `SurveySession.joins(:survey).find_by!(id: params[:id], survey: {user: current_user})`  try this

Comment: show the SQL exceptions also which helps quick debugging..

Comment: @test Nah, I get the same 'no such column' - exception, only difference is that it complains about survey.user and not anymore about surveys.user... :-/

Comment: @test Dude your last comment is correct, add as answer. :) It seems you are also not sure, which will be working.. :p

Comment: @ArupRakshit but he is saying that it's not working

Comment: @test `SurveySession.joins(:survey).find_by!(id: params[:id], surveys: {user_id: current_user})` -- added an s to survey and it works, thanks!

Comment: the first comment should run instead @Niggo

Comment: @test the first doesn't :-/

Comment: @test copied from source, yes, i just deleted the validations - I'm using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.1

Comment: `SurveySession.joins(:survey).find_by!(id: params[:id], survey: {user_id: current_user})` try this

Comment: This works, if you use **surveys** instead of **survey** as parameter for the find_by, unlogical to me, cause a session only has one parent survey, but maybe it's got to do something with the table names?

Comment: have you tried this `Survey.find_by!(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SurveySession.joins(:survey).find_by!(id: params[:id], surveys: {user_id: current_user})
```